# WebStorm does not display the same typescript "Initial type" as the test environment

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea, types, webstorm

I have a little problem, on WebStorm I don't have the same type value as on the test environment of typescript. This is a problem because it raises an error when using a function. The problem comes from the IDE ?

WebStorm:

[image: webstorm1]

TypeScript:

[image: typescript1]

WebStorm:

[image: webstorm2]

TypeScript:

[image: typescript2]

Comment: Are they using the same TypeScript version?

Comment: the error in the first screenshot comes from the Typescript compiler, not from the IDE, so it's not likely a problem with Webstorm; can be an issue with different versions of libraries (`d.ts`) files being used

Comment: No it doesn't seem to be a version problem and @lena the code is exactly the same on the typescript test environment as on the IDE so it's strange that for one it works fine and the other doesn't. Edit : I just tried on vscode and there is no type problem on it. But I need it to work on WebStorm too

Answer (score 0):

On my side, it happened because Webstorm couldn't find the nodejs binary in $PATH.

Specifying the nodejs binary path made it work as intented.